# Separate "each" to "types" in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a State, we have Shops, with database column `type` in each shop entry: **Grocery**, **Fashion** and **Food**.

I have the following code:

```
<% @country.states.each_with_index do |state, i| %>
  State <strong><%= i + 1 %></strong>

  <% state.shops.each do |shop| %>
    =====showing attributes of each shop=====
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In the code above, all shops will be listed according to IDs ascending:

```
Shop ID1 (Type = Food)
Shop ID2 (Type = Fashion)
Shop ID3 (Type = Grocery)
Shop ID4 (Type = Fashion)
Shop ID5 (Type = Food)
```

Instead of outputting `each`, I would like to show in the preferred `type` order:

```
Fashion
Shop ID2
Shop ID4

Grocery
Shop ID3

Food
Shop ID1
Shop ID5
```

I tried to use the `if state.shops.type == 'Fashion'` statement, but doesn't work. What is the proper way to write this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `group_by` method:

```
 <% @country.states.each_with_index do |state, i| %>
   State <strong><%= i + 1 %></strong>

   <% state.shops.group_by(&:type) do |type, shops| %>
     <h3><%= type %></h3>
     <% shops.each do |shop| %>
       =====showing attributes of each shop=====
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I would like to have preferred order to types to. Example, I want Fashion first, then Grocery, then Food.

Comment: Do this then: `state.shops(:order => 'type ASC').group_by(&:type)`

Comment: @wuputah, your order would result in Fashion, Food, Grocery instead. I won't be able to make a custom order.

Answer (score 0):

Following the earlier comments there doesn't seem to be any logic to the order that you want. So either you should implement an order attribute like an integer which you can use to sort by in the query. Otherwise you will have to create a block which will do static checks and do custom sorting, perhaps something like this:

```
@custom_order = {"Fashion" => 0, "Grocery" => 1, "Food" => 2}

<% state.shops.group_by(&:type).sort { |a, b|
  @custom_order[a.first] <=> @custom_order[b.first]
} do |type, shops| %>
```

As you see, it gets a little messy so I would probably add an order attribute as I mentioned and then do like wuputah said but change to

```
state.shops(:order => "order ASC").group_by(&:type)
```